# How to define Entry point for multiple implementation of interface using Hilt custom component?

Tags: android, custom-component, dagger-hilt, qualifiers

I have created a custom component `AuthUserComponent` using Hilt and need to provide multiple implementation to `DataRepository` interface.

```
class Sample @Inject constructor(
    @DemoMode private val demoRepository: DataRepository,
    @ProductionMode private val productionRepository: DataRepository
) {}
```

I have created the below @Provides implementations of the interface:

```
Module
@InstallIn(AuthUserComponent::class)
object DIModule {

    @AuthUserScope
    @DemoMode
    @Provides
    fun provideDataRepositoryImplDemo(): DataRepository =
        DataRepositoryImplDemo()

    @AuthUserScope
    @Provides
    @ProductionMode
    fun provideDataRepositoryImpl(): DataRepository =
        DataRepositoryImpl()
}
```

How do I provide multiple repository implementations via Entrypoint and bridge it with SingletonComponent? I get the below error:

> DataRepository is bound multiple times
> error

```
@InstallIn(AuthUserComponent::class)
@EntryPoint
 interface AuthUserDataEntryPoint {
    @ProductionMode
    fun dataRepositoryImpl(): DataRepository 
    @DemoMode
    fun dataRepositoryImplDemo(): DataRepository 
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal object AuthUserDataEntryBridge {
    @DemoMode
    @Provides
    internal fun provideDataRepositoryImplDemo(
        authUserComponentManager: AuthUserComponentManager
    ): DataRepository {
        return EntryPoints
            .get(authUserComponentManager, AuthUserDataEntryPoint::class.java)
            .dataRepositoryImplDemo()
    }

    @ProductionMode
    @Provides
    internal fun provideDataRepositoryImpl(
        authUserComponentManager: AuthUserComponentManager
    ): DataRepository {
        return EntryPoints
            .get(authUserComponentManager, AuthUserDataEntryPoint::class.java)
            .dataRepositoryImpl()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue to me seems to be that you are defining implementations in both `DIModule` and `AuthUserDataEntryBridge` for the same things. To be honest, I'm not really sure what the purpose of `AuthUserDataEntryBridge` is and I'm unfamiliar with the usage of `EntryPoints` inside a class annotated with `@Module`.

Is there are reason you can't just do this install this in the `SingletonComponent` directly:

```
Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DIModule {

    @DemoMode
    @Provides
    fun provideDataRepositoryImplDemo(): DataRepository =
        DataRepositoryImplDemo()

    @Provides
    @ProductionMode
    fun provideDataRepositoryImpl(): DataRepository =
        DataRepositoryImpl()
}
```

That seems to be the core of the issue here. I'm guessing its because of the custom component / scope. In that case, I think you just need to use `EntryPoints` where you are actually injecting the repositories:

```
class Sample {
    private lateinit var demoRepository: DataRepository
    private lateinit var productionRepository: DataRepository

    fun inject(authUserComponent: AuthUserComponent) {
       val entryPoint = EntryPoints.get(authUserComponent, AuthUserDataEntryPoint:class.java)
       demoRepository = entryPoint.demoRepositoryImpl()
       productionRepository = entryPoint.productionRepositoryImpl()
    }

}
```

But I don't think you're going to get away with trying to hide the `EntryPoints` usage inside a module definition.